# Make Pie Chart in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular2-template, pie-chart

How to make pie chart in Angular 5. I am hard coded data (data not from API) and want make pie chart in basis of expiration and lot satus. Below is my code

component.html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="expiration">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Expiration </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let csvdata"> {{csvdata.expiration}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="lotstatus">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Lot Status </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let csvdata"> {{csvdata.lotstatus}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

component.ts

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  { type: 'MEDIA', id: 'SAB', name: 'Sabour aud Dextros e Agar', location: 'SLAB', department: 'MICS', workstation: '', manufacturer: '', lotnumber: '2337515', opened: '28/7/17', closed: '', recieved: '', registration: '', expiration: '', lotstatus: 'A', norecieved: '1 Packs', units: '1 Packs', subunits: '0', test: '' },
  { type: 'CONTROL', id: 'AFBQ CSLI DES', name: 'AFB Stain Control Slides', location: 'SLAB', department: 'MICS', workstation: '', manufacturer: 'REMEL', lotnumber: '00968', opened: '', closed: '', recieved: '', registration: '', expiration: '', lotstatus: 'A', norecieved: '1 Boxes', units: '1 Packs', subunits: '0', test: '' },
  { type: 'MEDIA', id: 'SAB', name: 'Sabour aud Dextros e Agar', location: 'SLAB', department: 'MICS', workstation: '', manufacturer: '', lotnumber: '2337515', opened: '', closed: '', recieved: '', registration: '', expiration: '', lotstatus: 'A', norecieved: '1 Packs', units: '1 Packs', subunits: '0', test: '' },
  { type: 'CONTROL', id: 'AFBQ CSLI DES', name: 'AFB Stain Control Slides', location: 'SLAB', department: 'MICS', workstation: '', manufacturer: 'REMEL', lotnumber: '00968', opened: '', closed: '', recieved: '', registration: '', expiration: '', lotstatus: 'A', norecieved: '1 Boxes', units: '1 Packs', subunits: '0', test: '' },
  { type: 'MEDIA', id: 'SAB', name: 'Sabour aud Dextros e Agar', location: 'SLAB', department: 'MICS', workstation: '', manufacturer: '', lotnumber: '2337515', opened: '', closed: '', recieved: '', registration: '', expiration: '', lotstatus: 'A', norecieved: '1 Packs', units: '1 Packs', subunits: '0', test: '' },
  { type: 'CONTROL', id: 'AFBQ CSLI DES', name: 'AFB Stain Control Slides', location: 'SLAB', department: 'MICS', workstation: '', manufacturer: 'REMEL', lotnumber: '00968', opened: '', closed: '', recieved: '', registration: '', expiration: '', lotstatus: 'A', norecieved: '1 Boxes', units: '1 Packs', subunits: '0', test: '' },
  { type: 'MEDIA', id: 'SAB', name: 'Sabour aud Dextros e Agar', location: 'SLAB', department: 'MICS', workstation: '', manufacturer: '', lotnumber: '2337515', opened: '', closed: '', recieved: '', registration: '', expiration: '', lotstatus: 'A', norecieved: '1 Packs', units: '1 Packs', subunits: '0', test: '' },
  { type: 'CONTROL', id: 'AFBQ CSLI DES', name: 'AFB Stain Control Slides', location: 'SLAB', department: 'MICS', workstation: '', manufacturer: 'REMEL', lotnumber: '00968', opened: '', closed: '', recieved: '', registration: '', expiration: '', lotstatus: 'A', norecieved: '1 Boxes', units: '1 Packs', subunits: '0', test: '' },
  { type: 'MEDIA', id: 'SAB', name: 'Sabour aud Dextros e Agar', location: 'SLAB', department: 'MICS', workstation: '', manufacturer: '', lotnumber: '2337515', opened: '', closed: '', recieved: '', registration: '', expiration: '', lotstatus: 'A', norecieved: '1 Packs', units: '1 Packs', subunits: '0', test: '' },
  { type: 'CONTROL', id: 'AFBQ CSLI DES', name: 'AFB Stain Control Slides', location: 'SLAB', department: 'MICS', workstation: '', manufacturer: 'REMEL', lotnumber: '00968', opened: '', closed: '', recieved: '', registration: '', expiration: '', lotstatus: 'A', norecieved: '1 Boxes', units: '1 Packs', subunits: '0', test: '' },
  { type: 'MEDIA', id: 'SAB', name: 'Sabour aud Dextros e Agar', location: 'SLAB', department: 'MICS', workstation: '', manufacturer: '', lotnumber: '2337515', opened: '', closed: '', recieved: '', registration: '', expiration: '', lotstatus: 'A', norecieved: '1 Packs', units: '1 Packs', subunits: '0', test: '' },
  { type: 'CONTROL', id: 'AFBQ CSLI DES', name: 'AFB Stain Control Slides', location: 'SLAB', department: 'MICS', workstation: '', manufacturer: 'REMEL', lotnumber: '00968', opened: '', closed: '', recieved: '', registration: '', expiration: '', lotstatus: 'A', norecieved: '1 Boxes', units: '1 Packs', subunits: '0', test: '' }    
];
```

Comment: Have a look at angular-chart.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use [D3js](https://d3js.org/)

You can do a lot of charts. Like [PieChart](http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1203641)

You can find here a tutorial: [Create a Pie Chart with Dynamic Data Using D3.js & Angular 2](http://www.palador.com/2017/02/28/create-a-pie-chart-with-dynamic-data-using-d3-js-angular-2/)

Comment: Thanks you @Wandrille Its really save my time & helpful for me.
Can I make Line chart using D3js.?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you take a look at [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/).

I've recently used it with Angular 6, to render pie and bar charts that affect each other on click. I think it's easy to use, you can find answers online and the documentation is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned you can use chart.js as a dependency and generate the pie chart as you need,

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
```

Personally i've used chart.js with angularjs and angular it works quite nicely. If you like to use any package go with [`ngx-charts`](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts) which internally uses chart.js

Comment: May I make line chart using ngx-charts.?

Comment: Yes just change the chart type . Mark if this helped

Answer (score 0):

Another options:

- [Kendo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/series-types/pie/#toc-data-binding)
- [Ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-charts/pie-series/#example-basic-pie)
- [ngx-charts](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts)
- [primefaces](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/chart/pie)